# apache bean unable to serialize due to interface that I want to mock

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

unable to serialize DoFnWithExecutionInformation{doFn=com.orderly.dataflow.RosterFileReader@60ec7684, mainOutputTag=Tag, sideInputMapping={}, schemaInformation=DoFnSchemaInformation{elementConverters=[]}}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize DoFnWithExecutionInformation{doFn=com.orderly.dataflow.RosterFileReader@60ec7684, mainOutputTag=Tag, sideInputMapping={}, schemaInformation=DoFnSchemaInformation{elementConverters=[]}}

I am not sure this is possible.  I understand in apache beam, these functions must be serializable for scaling out but during test time I also want to mock where we read from.

Is there some kind of context or something I can create to inject the interface which is mockable for reading?

Here is my code

```
public class RosterFileReader extends DoFn<String, PractitionerStandardOutputDto> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RosterFileReader.class);

    private final String projectId;
    private GCPBucketStorage storage;

    public RosterFileReader(String projectId, GCPBucketStorage storage) {
```

I am wondering if there is a context I can send in?  GCPBucketStorage.java is OUR API since googles was not that mockable.  In this way, we have full control of throwing exceptions and testing recovery as well as other scenarios.

EDIT: I would be willing to settle for some code like this

```
if(isRunningLocally) {
     storage = new MockStorage();
} else { 
     storage = new GCPBucketStorageImpl();
}
```

it basically kind of sucks having test code like that in production code, but this END to END test has already caught bugs!!!!!!  bugs that are missed in the unit testing that people are doing.  We generally do not do single class or unit testing and only do what twitter calls Feature Testing since it allows huge refactors without touching tests -> https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/insights/2017/the-testing-renaissance.html

I can reach into the Mock using static fields I guess(Again, I hate doing that but this test is so valuable having it end to end truly)

EDIT 2: Is serialization a ton like hadoop where you have to define classes to deploy along with the main jar?  Perhaps I just need a document to make GCPStorage and GCPBucketStorageImpl serializable (and MockStorage as well most likely since it is in production code :( ) -> The if..else is totally worth it on the integration bugs we are finding pre-CI so people don't break the code on master ever.

EDIT 3:
This looks very promising -> https://gist.github.com/jlewi/f1cd323dc88bd58601ef
Will update post after trying.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

Actually, just making the interface serializable seems to work in test (not tested in production yet) Along with this last line in the production code that is ugly(and I wonder if I can inject this instead) ->

[image]

yup, pretty ugly to have test code in production :(. **Of BIG worth note is instead of injecting the interface, I inject GCPBucketStorageImpl.java (our prod implemntation) and now pass in the mock(which subclasses the prod class** <---- This is done so we get test validation on someone modifying production class to not being serializable in which case we would not catch the issue.